# C++ Compile error on Github project

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the code from the below github location and getting an error any help much appreciated

Github project is https://github.com/aranetic/process-pst

Error is

```
~/process-pst (master ✘)✭  ᐅ make
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ProcessPstLib.dir/edrm.cpp.o
/Users/gwest/process-pst/edrm.cpp: In function 'void<unnamed>::output_file(edrm_context&,        const std::wstring&, const std::wstring&, const std::vector<unsigned char,    std::allocator<unsigned char> >&)':
/Users/gwest/process-pst/edrm.cpp:177: error: 'class boost::filesystem::path' has no     member named 'file_string'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ProcessPstLib.dir/edrm.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ProcessPstLib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From what you can see in [boost/filesystem/path.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/filesystem/path.hpp):

```
# if defined(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATED)
    //  deprecated functions with enough signature or semantic changes that they are
    //  not supplied by default 
    const std::string file_string() const               { return string(); }

    // ...

# endif
```

file_string() is "not supplied by default". So you have three choices:

1. Recompile boost without BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DEPRECATED flag
2. Use older boost library.
3. Correct source code you're trying to compile.

Comment: The last commit on the project was 3 years ago, so there's the problem.